# File being used by process

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012

I have 2 SSIS packages. The first one loads an excel file into the DB. The second archives the excel files. When I run both from a master package, the archive package fails with error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.".

I have tried File.Move, File.Copy then File.Delete, disposing and releasing the connections, pausing for 30 seconds, and I have RetainSameConnection set to false. Any other ideas?

Comment: can you share the methods that work on the file? you have either a race condition, or you do not release the file handle before trying to archive it.

Answer (score 0):

Get the process ID of first SSID than kill ✌️